How do I find the angle alpha given that I have a scalene triangle, and only know the length of one side of that triangle?
[scalene triangle where only one angle is known, and one side is known. There is a possible right triangle drawn as apart of the smallest side of the scalene triangle.][1]
Hey all, having trouble with a problem and figured I'd ask here for advice/help. It's been some time since I've done geometry quite like this so bare with me. I have a scalene triangle where one of the angles is known, which we'll say is $\theta = 20^{o}$. AB and CB are unknown in this setup, but CD = 2, and BD is also unknown. With the information provided is it possible to figure out $\alpha$, AB, and CB? Sorry if I haven't explained this well, the photo included should provide a bit more clarity.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What I would like to do is figure out if there is a way to figure out what alpha is in the photo, as well as figuring out the sides of the larger triangle.

Your picture indicate that $AC=75$ but your post tells that $AC$ is unknown. If $AC$ is known, this is a simple trigonometric question. If $AC$ is unknown, there are no unique solution.

AC is known, sorry. So would the solution to this be the first answer here (with r/sin(90))?

HINTS:
Find complementary angles
For $R$ use Sine trig Rule
$$ \frac{R}{\sin 90^{\circ}}= R= ~\frac{AC+CD}{\sin 70^{\circ}} = \frac{77}{\cos 20^{\circ}}$$
From triangle ABD $$ BD= 77 \tan 20^{\circ}$$
$$ \alpha= \tan ^{-1}\frac{2}{BD}=  \tan ^{-1}\frac{2}{ 77 \tan 20^{\circ}}. $$

How did you figure out that angle at B was 70? Sorry it's been a while so I'm bit rusty with geometry.

AD is perpendicular  to AD. So if angle at A is 20 degrees, then angles total  at B should be ( 90-20=70 ) degrees.

Would theta still be the same for triangle ABD as it would be for ABC in that case?

Ok, so you are working on it,  edited my answer.

I am not quite sure I understood you correctly. My assumtions are:

$AC=75$
$CD = 2$
$\theta = 20^\circ$.

Then we have$$
AD = AC+CD = 77.
$$
We know that $$
\tan \theta = \frac{BD}{AD}
$$ or equivalently
$$
BD = AD \cdot \tan \theta.
$$ Pythagoras gives
$$
R = \sqrt{AD^2 + BD^2}
$$. All that is left to compute is $\alpha$. Note that $\alpha$ itself is the angle of a smaller triangle. We know that$$
\tan \alpha = \frac{CD}{BD}
$$ or equivalently $$
\alpha = \arctan\left(\frac{CD}{BD}\right)
$$. Plugging in all the numbers will give you the desired results.
